# How to customise tooltip format in Sankey diagram

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-google-charts

I'm having trouble in customising the tooltip format.
[Default tooltip format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n97XC.png)

I'm expecting that we're able to update the font style of tooltip, its format and the style of tooltip box.

Expected result:
**Label1 > Label2**
count